# Why the RHS got evaluated when the LHS is FALSE for and operation in R?

Tags: r

I was expecting that for "and" operations RHS expression will not be evaluated if the LHS expression is evaluated to `FALSE`.

However, while this (1) works fine:

```
'xxx' %in% names(mtcars) & all(mtcars$xxx > 0)
# [1] FALSE
```

This one (2) gives a warnings:

```
'xxx' %in% names(mtcars) & sum(!is.na(mtcars$xxx)) > 0
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In is.na(mtcars$xxx) :
#   is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Clearly, this error suggest that the RHS of above line is evaluated.
As `'xxx' %in% names(mtcars)` is `FALSE`, why `sum(!is.na(mtcars$xxx)) > 0` got evaluated? And why there is no warning whith the first one?

Comment: Only && and || short circuit. & and | do not.  See `?Logic` .

Comment: If output doesn't match your expectation you should usually study the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `&&` operator to short-circuit.

```
> FALSE & stop("hey")
Error: hey
> FALSE && stop("hey")
[1] FALSE
```

From `?'&'`:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate
>   for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

As to why the first didn't creating an error/warning... it's because there isn't anything to give a warning about.  We can take it step by step to see what happens.

```
> mtcars$xxx
NULL
> NULL > 0
logical(0)
> all(logical(0))
[1] TRUE
```

Note that the last part is perfectly in line with the documentation.  From `?all`:

> The value returned is TRUE if all of the values in x are TRUE
>   (including if there are no values)

Comment: It seems that I was led to think the RHS is not evaluated due to the strange behavior of `all`. It's odd that `any(NULL)` is FALSE while `all(NULL)` is TRUE.

Comment: @mt1022 A bit odd but somewhat consistent depending on how you think of it.  When doing `all(NULL)` you're asking "are all of the values in here true" and since there aren't any values it's vacuously true.  When doing `any(NULL)` you're asking "are there any TRUE values in here"? And that is FALSE since there isn't a TRUE value.  So it may seem odd that something can be "all TRUE but not have any TRUE values" it's at least consistent with the logical definitions.